# CMake, thirdparties, Ninja and cleaning

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to replace a (slow) build tool in my company with CMake.

Our current build tool has this nice feature that it can extract a tag from some sub repositories, and then uses it to download (using a package manager similar to rpm that would handle only a development package) third parties matching the version number.

The additional problem being that the repository manager would install packages to a shared directory used by multiple users: files installed in that shared directory must not be deleted when doing a "make clean" or a "ninja clean".

I've been trying to replicate that behaviour with CMake. So far I'm able to make this work with Make, but not with Ninja.

Try #1:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/somelib.a
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_FILE=${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a -DRPM_ARG=someLib:${SOMELIB_VERSION} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rpm_install.cmake)
add_custom_target(checkSomeLib DEPENDS ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a)
add_library(someLib_rpm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SHARED_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a)
add_dependencies(someLib_rpm check_SomeLib)
```

with rpm_install.cmake being:

```
if (NOT EXISTS ${TEST_FILE})
    execute_process(
        COMMAND custom_pm install ${RPM_ARG})
endif()
```

That works well: if the file is not present, it gets installed.
Problem: "make clean" remove installed files.

The solution would be to mark the directory with CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM. That works with make, but not with Ninja.

Try #2:

Since Make and Ninja clean those files because they are declared as being OUTPUT, let's not declare them as OUTPUT:

```
add_custom_target(checkSomelib
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_FILE=${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a -DRPM_ARG=someLib:${SOMELIB_VERSION} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rpm_install.cmake)
add_library(someLib_rpm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SHARED_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a)
add_dependencies(someLib_rpm check_SomeLib)
```

It's a slight variation of try #1.
It works with Make, but not with Ninja since Ninja knows no rule able to create the library in the first place!

Try #3: use ExternalProject_Add

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
  someLib
  SOURCE_DIR sharedInstalledDir
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ""
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_FILE=${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a -DRPM_ARG=someLib:${SOMELIB_VERSION} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rpm_install.cmake
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  TEST_COMMAND ""
)
add_library(someLib_rpm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SHARED_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a)
```

And the problem is that "make clean" and "ninja clean" still clean the library...

I guess I could make try #2 work with Ninja by adding a configure step so that missing libraries are downloaded at creation time.

The problem is it would work "statically", not "dynamically": if an update in a sub-repository indicates a newer version of a library, then the check step would fail since someLib.a would not exist yet. (There are some versionning information in the naming of `someLib.a`.)

I guess I could put in place something more complicated like this (I did not try it yet):

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT somelibLnk.a
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_FILE=${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a -DRPM_ARG=someLib:${SOMELIB_VERSION} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rpm_install.cmake
                   COMMAND ln -s ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a someLibLnk.a)
add_custom_target(checkSomeLib DEPENDS someLibLnk.a)
add_library(someLib_rpm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SHARED_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION someLibLnk.a)
add_dependencies(someLib_rpm check_SomeLib)
```

The idea is being to create a link to the real library. The link can be removed no problem. If it does not exist, then it triggers the download and creates the link.

But is there a simpler solution?

Update 1:

I've replaced all those tries by:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DTEST_FILE=${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a -DRPM_ARG=someLib:${SOMELIB_VERSION} -P {CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rpm_install.cmake)
add_library(someLib_rpm STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SHARED_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET someLib_rpm APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${SHARED_DIR}/lib/someLib.a)
```

So that dependencies get installed at configure time.

That works fine with dependencies where the version number is hard coded into CMakeLists.txt.

This also solves the problem with "make clean" and "ninja clean" since no libraries/executables are the OUTPUT of a target. And this is simple.

I'm now trying to find a solution for "dynamic" version numbers. (The one that get extracted from Git at build time.)

My plan is to add a custom_target that triggers an external CMake script that will extract the Git version information and then update a .cmake file that will be included in a CMakeLists.txt.
My hope is this will re-trigger CMake and all will be well. Do you think that might work?

Update 2:

That does not work, although I'm able to do what's described above. This does not trigger a rebuild_cache.

For those interested, I did something like this:

```
if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/someLib_version.cmake)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DDIR=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DDST=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/someLib_version.cmake -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/extract_version.cmake)
endif()
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/someLib_version.cmake)
add_custom_target(extract_version ALL
              COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DDIR=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DDST=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/someLib_version.cmake -DSRC_DIR=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -DBIN_DIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/extract_version.cmake)
```

And extract_version.cmake being:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --tags --match someLib_v*
    COMMAND cut -c6-
    WORKING_DIRECTORY  ${DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE SOMELIB_VERSION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
file(WRITE ${DST}.tmp "set(SOMELIB_VERSION ${SOMELIB_VERSION})")

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${DST}.tmp ${DST})
#execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -H${SRC_DIR} -B${BIN_DIR})
```

At that point, I don't know how to resolve my use case with CMake. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: `make clean` is kind of antithetical to the "cmake" way of doing things, and you'll run across difficulties writing scripts constants if you try to use it. The "cmake" way is to do an out-of-source build, and to clean by deleting the build folder. As long as your "installed" files go somewhere else, you won't blow them away.

Comment: The build is already out of tree. However it can take quite some time to compile, and sometime, just to make sure, it's good to be able to do a make clean in a subdir. As for ninja, you're right "ninja clean" should not be invoked, but if it is, I don't want to have all people screaming because some (shared) files disappeared.

Comment: Deleting a subdirectory does not work? Rerunning CMake should re-create the subdirectory but not trigger the rebuild of other parts.

Comment: Yes, I guess that might work. However I get the feeling this is just a workaround. What I want is to have the build system work according to our use case. Again, if a user executes a "ninja clean" by error, I don't want other users screaming because some shared files disappeared.